# 'undefined debug reason 7 - target needs reset' Error when debug ARM Cortex-M33 using OpenOCD in FTDI SWD Mode

Tags: cortex-m, ftdi, gdbserver, openocd, swd

I am currently using OpenOCD to debug Cortex-M33 processor. However, after it connects to gdb and starts debugging, it shows the following message:

```
Try to search windows process
Found openocd running, Kill it
SUCCESS: The process "openocd.exe" with PID 18768 has been terminated.
Open On-Chip Debugger 0.10.0
Licensed under GNU GPL v2
For bug reports, read
        http://openocd.org/doc/doxygen/bugs.html
Info : FTDI SWD mode enabled
adapter speed: 1000 kHz
adapter_nsrst_delay: 200
cortex_mX3 reset_config sysresetreq
Info : clock speed 1000 kHz
Info : SWD DPIDR 0x6ba02477
Info : rtl8722csm.cpu: hardware has 2 breakpoints, 1 watchpoints
Info : accepting 'gdb' connection on tcp/3333
undefined debug reason 7 - target needs reset
target halted due to debug-request, current mode: Thread
xPSR: 0x01000000 pc: 0x00000100 msp: 0x0008fffc
Error: address + size wrapped (0xfffffffe, 0x00000004)
Error: address + size wrapped (0xfffffffe, 0x00000004)
Info : SWD DPIDR 0x6ba02477
Error: Failed to read memory at 0x00000000
Info : SWD DPIDR 0x6ba02477
Error: Failed to read memory at 0x00000000
Polling target rtl8722csm.cpu failed, trying to reexamine
Info : SWD DPIDR 0x6ba02477
Info : rtl8722csm.cpu: hardware has 2 breakpoints, 1 watchpoints
target halted due to debug-request, current mode: Thread
xPSR: 0x61000000 pc: 0x0c004132 psp: 0x00089a58
target halted due to debug-request, current mode: Thread
xPSR: 0x01000000 pc: 0x00000100 msp: 0x0008fffc
```

I am not quite familiar with OpenOCD settings, so what could be the possible reason for this 'debug reason 7' issue or how could I identify the cause of the problem? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

"reason 7" is `DBG_REASON_EXC_CATCH` and means OpenOCD catched an exception.  I don't know how you execute your OpenOCD but it seems something bad has happened.   Reset your target to see what happens.